# Update array in Factory on the fly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I need to do a simple app where i can make appear embed videos with the click of a button. 
I did have a lot of troubles to make my embed players to dynamically bind but i did it!

I made a factory which contains my datas in an array form.

Those data are generating a list of buttons and when i click on one of these button i want the related player to be displayed. To do that i need to toggle the 'tv' value of the previous video displayed and toogle the one i just clicked.

**Controller :**

```
'use strict';
 angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('MyAppCtrl', function ($scope, datas) {
     $scope.awesomeThings = [
       'HTML5 Boilerplate',
       'AngularJS',
       'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.lives = datas.getLives();
 });
```

**Factory :**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('datas', function () {
    var factory = {};
    var lives = [
      {id:'1', title:'title1', tv: 'false', code:'code1'},
      {id:'2', title:'title2', tv: 'true', code:'code2'}
    ];
    factory.getLives = function () {
      return lives;
    };    
    return factory;
  });
```

**Directive for the embed player :**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('dmcloud', function($sce) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      scope: { code:'=' },
      template: '<iframe width="512" height="288" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ng-src="{{url}}"></iframe>',
      link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('code', function (newVal) {
          if (newVal) {
            scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://api.dmcloud.net/player/embed/' + newVal);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

**and finally my view**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="live in lives">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="lives.toogleLive()" value="{{live.title}}">
  </li>
</ul> 

<h2>TV : </h2>

<div ng-repeat="live in lives | filter:tv = true">
  <dmcloud code="live.code"></dmcloud>
</div>
```

As you can see I am filtering my data with the **tv** key to only display the one where it is set to *true*. But i Can't find a clean way to change the appropriate tv value.  I don't know what to do and where to place my toogleLive() function.

If you have an idea i'm all ears!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3oNbv1hXHixYcGZqEJug?p=preview
I change `<iframe>` to `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your directive appears to be setup to handle changes to the code attribute.  So why not have an *activeTv* property that stores a reference to the currently selected live TV.

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="live in lives">
<input type="submit" ng-click="activeTv = live" value="{{live.title}}">
</li>
</ul> 

<h2>TV : </h2>

<div>
<dmcloud code="activeTv.code"></dmcloud>
</div>
```